# How to approach the Fair Cut challenge on Hackerrank?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am stuck on a competitive programming challenge:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fair-cut/problem

What I tried: sorting the array taking median of the array, and using 2 pointers one for left traversing and other for right traversing and checking for minimizing differences (this is not a DP approach btw). This approach worked for about 10 out of 21 test cases.

I have been struggling at modeling the dynamic programming table for this problem. So how to write a logical recurrence relation for this problem? Any insights or hints for the problem would be appreciated.

#### Problem statement:

Li and Lu have `n` integers, `a_1, a_2, ..., a_n`, that they want to divide fairly between the two of them. They decide that if Li gets integers with indices `I = {i_1, i_2, ..., i_k}` (which implies that Lu gets integers with indices `J = {1, ..., n} \ I`), then the measure of unfairness of this division is:

```
f(I) = sum |a_i - a_j| for i <- I, j <- J
```

Find the minimum measure of unfairness that can be obtained with some division of the set of integers where Li gets exactly `k` integers.

Note `A \ B` means Set complement.

Answer (score 0):

How about this idea? Consider `A` sorted from large to small. Let `f(i, j)` represent a tuple: (1) the minimum measure of unfairness that can be obtained with some division of the set of integers up to index `i` where `Li` gets exactly `j` integers, (2) `sum(I)`. Then:

```
f(i, j) = min(
  f(i-1, j),

  let r = f(m, j-1)
      // Subtract the difference of Ai from larger a's in I
   in r[0] - (r[1] - |I| * Ai) +
      // Subtract Ai from larger a's in J if applicable
      prefixSum(i-1) - r[1] - (i - 1 - |I|) * Ai +
      // Subtract smaller a's in J from Ai if applicable
      (|J| - (i - 1 - |I|) - 1) * Ai - (sum(J) - (prefixSum(i-1) - r[1]) - Ai)
)
for all (j-1) <= m < i
```

Complexity is possibly `O(n * k = n^2)`. The only thing I'm confused about is that we can have multiple `sum(I)`'s when the minimum is duplicated, as in the example below. In that case, I wonder if each one can yield a different solution for the next `k`. At any rate, we can at least narrow the search space to the minimums. We can also observe and avoid recalculating the same `(min, sum (I))` tuple in the same `i` iteration.

Let's sort the numbers in the first example from large to small:

```
k = 2
4 3 1 2

=> 4 3 2 1
```

Initialise `f(i, 1)`:

```
                                                  (min, sum(I))
a_i: 4 =>  4 * 3 - sum(1,2,3)       = 12 - 6    = (6,   4     )

a_i: 3 =>  4 - 3 + 2 * 3 - sum(1,2) = 1 + 6 - 3 = (4,   3     )
a_i: 2 =>  sum(4,3) - 2 * 2 + 2 - 1 = 7 - 4 + 1 = (4,   2 or 3)
a_i: 1 =>  sum(4,3,2) - 3 * 1       = 9 - 3     = (4,   2 or 3)
```

Iterate `f(i, 2)`:

```
a_i: 4 =>  Infinity

a_i: 3 =>  min(
             Infinity,

             6 - (4 - 1 * 3) +
             4 - 4 - (1 - 1) * 3 +
             (3 - 1) * 3 - (6 - (4 - 4) - 3)

           ) = (8, 3 + 4 = 7) // (min, sum(I))

a_i: 2 =>  min(
             8,

             6 - (4 - 1 * 2) +
             7 - 4 - (2 - 1) * 2 +
             (3 - (2 - 1) - 1) * 2 - (6 - (7 - 4) - 2)
             = (6, 2 + 4 = 6), // (min, sum(I))

             4 - (3 - 1 * 2) + 
             7 - 3 - (2 - 1) * 2 +
             (3 - (2 - 1) - 1) * 2 - (7 - (7 - 3) - 2)
             = (6, 2 + 3 = 5) // (min, sum(I))

           ) = (6, 5 or 6) // (min, sum(I))

a_i: 1 =>  min(
             (6, 5 or 6),

             6 - (4 - 1 * 1) +
             9 - 4 - (3 - 1) * 1 +
             (3 - (3 - 1) - 1) * 1 - (6 - (9 - 4) - 1)
             = (6, 4 + 1 = 5),  // (min, sum(I))

             4 - (3 - 1 * 1) + 
             9 - 3 - (3 - 1) * 1 +
             (3 - (3 - 1) - 1) * 1 - (7 - (9 - 3) - 1)
             = (6, 3 + 1 = 4),  // (min, sum(I))

             4 - (2 - 1 * 1) + 
             9 - 2 - (3 - 1) * 1 +
             N / A
             = (8, 1 + 2 = 3)  // (min, sum(I))

           ) = (6, 4 5 or 6)  // (min, sum(I))
```